# Intel Graphics Board doesn't run great at Ubuntu. Help me?

Tags: performance

It's my first ask here, so sorry for something...
I have a notebook ( 3Gb Ram, Core 2 Duo @ 2,1Ghz , Intel Graphics 4 1GB Onboard) and when I open more than 3, 4 softwares, and try to alternate between them, using the "Super + W" , I got some legs and low performance. sometimes the Unity crash and restart because. While watching some videos on Youtube, and open the Dash, the "transparency" behind Dash looks very Legged, sometimes the image Freeze behing the Dash layer. When I was a Windows 7 user, I could open 10 softwares and alternate between 'em using "Super = Tab" without any troubles. I was able to Play Burnout Paradise, a heavy game, with aero Turned ON! This way I believe  this trouble is with the default driver came with ubuntu 11.10 (and 12.04). While using Ubuntu 10.10, this didn't happien. So , My question is.... Is there some driver I can Download to improve my video's board speed? Can I do something?

P.S. = I prefer the workflow Unity, It's easier, prettier and agiler than Windows 7 UI

P.S. 2 = Sorry about my bad english, I'm Brazilian, and here just about 5% can speak english. "I didn't use google translator :P)

Thanks for the answers :D  God blesses you!

Answer (score 0):

What you could do, first, is use **Unity 2D**. **Unity 2D** isn't really behind **Unity 3D**, so you would get better performance and still be able to use **Ubuntu** as it's.

A second option would be use **xorg-edgers**, a PPA that updates your drivers to the latest ones avaiable. But those are **EXPERIMENTAL** drivers and are dangerous, so only use it if you are absolutely sure you want to use them. As they say: **this PPA can put your computer on fire** hehe

[Since you are from Brazil, you can read this article i wrote about **xorg-edgers**](http://www.ubuntubrsc.com/xorg-edgers-melhore-performance-da-sua-placa-de-video-ubuntu.html).

Hope it helps you, but again: **xorg-edgers** have **EXPERIMENTAL and not tested** drivers and **can break your desktop**, so only use if you know what you are doing. I never had any problem with it (*Intel HD 3000 Sandy Bridge*), but i have to warn you that i can give you trouble.

Answer (score -1):

open jocky-gtk(default installed), check is there are any suggestion for graphics driver? if any install it. Otherwise these step maybe help,

open /etc/default/grub file

```
sudo gedit /etc/default/grub
```

change the line

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="" to  GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="nomodeset"
```

update grub

```
sudo update-grub
```

Reboot

Comment: `nomodeset` disables the Intel driver which forces a 1024x768 VESA resolution